# How do I read a secret file in a container docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I attach a file to docker-compose:

```
environment:
      - "MSMTP_CONFIG_FILE=/run/secrets/msmtprc"
```

The php.ini uses this file in this way:

```
sendmail_path = "msmtp -C $MSMTP_CONFIG_FILE -t"
```

But in the logs it gives the following:

```
msmtp: /run/secrets/msmtprc: contains secrets and therefore must be owned by you
```

The file has permission **1000:1000**. I tried to create a group with such a gid and add the user **www-data** there, but it did not help. How to read data from a file correctly?